# Can I build part of my website in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, url-routing, rails-routing

I have an existing website written in jsp. I want to rewrite a part of the website. The url for that section can either be **newpart.mysite.com** or **mysite.com/newpart**.

Will it be possible to rewrite this new part in **Ruby** on **Rails**? How does the routing works for both the url options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use ROR for a portion of your site.

If your using a webhost they will route the domain to a folder on your server.

The way you worded your question, it seems as if your "newpart" will be a separate interface than the rest of the code for your site. You can act as if they are on different servers basically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

For your options:
If you point the whole subdomain at rails: newpart.mysite.com, then all you have to do is tell apache (or whatever you use) to redirect that URL to your RoR app - and the app will happily continue from there without any changes to routing.

It would be more complex if you wanted to use: mysite.com/newpart ... so if you have a choice, I'd go with the subdomain.